# Windows Server Resolução DNS condicional

Tags: windows, servidor, script, dns

Bom dia tenho um windows server a funcionar como DNS server mas queria colocar uma formatação condicional para que caso o resultado da Query fosse um IP especifico, que resolvesse noutro dns.